# IndentationError in python script for organising Music

Tags: python, linux, symlink, archlinux

I have made this script in the past and I want to use it now, but an error occurs when trying to run it. This script is about organising my music. I have a directory organised by label and want to grab the artist name from the directory names inside label and year directory and create new directories inside the artist and year directory.

The names of directories inside label are like this

LabelName_[Artist-AlbumName]_2015-08-09

And want to create symlinks inside artist directories and year directories( by date ) like this

2015-08-09_[Artist-AlbumName]_LabelName

```
import os
basedir = "/home/zab/Music/#01.Label"
artist_parent_dir = "/home/zab/Music/#03.Artist"
date_parent_dir = "/home/zab/Music/#04.ReleaseDate"
for fn in os.listdir(basedir):
    label_path = os.path.join( basedir, fn)
    for album in os.listdir(label_path):
        i = 1
        words = album.split("_")
        for word in words:
            if i == 1:
                label = word
            elif i == 2:
                name = word
            else:
                date = word
            i = i + 1
        artist_album = name.split("-")
        j = 1
        for part in artist_album:
            if j == 1:
                artist = part.replace("[","")
            j = j + 1
        date_parts = date.split("-")
        z =  1
        for part_two in date_parts:
            if z == 1:
                year = part_two
            z = z + 1
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(artist_parent_dir,artist)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(artist_parent_dir,artist))
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(date_parent_dir,year)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(date_parent_dir,year))
        src = os.path.join(label_path,album)
        artist_dst = os.path.join(artist_parent_dir, artist, name + "_" + label + "_" + date)
        year_dst = os.path.join(date_parent_dir,year, date + "_" + name + "_" + label)
        if not os.path.exists(artist_dst):
            os.symlink(src, artist_dst)
        if not os.path.exists(year_dst):
            os.symlink(src, year_dst)

File "/home/zab/Music/_Scripts/OrganizeByArtist.py", line 22
    artist = part.replace("[","")
                                ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What is going wrong? Is part.replace outdated or something?
Any suggestion to improve this script would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an indentation error , this has nothing to do with replace, you have a mixture of tabs and spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably mixing spaces and tabs, which makes it hard to figure out how Python sees the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing tabs and spaces; taking the source from your post here shows:

```
>>> '''\
...             for part in artist_album:
...                 if j == 1:
...                     artist = part.replace("[","")
... '''.splitlines()
['            for part in artist_album:', '\t            if j == 1:', '                    artist = part.replace("[","")']
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
['            for part in artist_album:',
 '\t            if j == 1:',
 '                    artist = part.replace("[","")']
```

Note the `\t` at the start of the `if` line. Python expands tabs to *8 spaces*, but you probably have your editor set to use 4 spaces instead. So Python sees this:

```
for part in artist_album:
        if j == 1:
        artist = part.replace("[","")']
```

where your editor shows you this:

```
for part in artist_album:
    if j == 1:
        artist = part.replace("[","")']
```

Configure your editor to use *spaces only* for indentation. A good editor will convert <kbd>TAB</kbd> keys into spaces for you if so configured.

Quoting from the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) (PEP 8):

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.